# Perl Regex to Grep a word not starting with special character _

Tags: regex, perl

i want a perl regex to grep a word from the following output:

```
Process Completed;Result= Volume in drive D has no label.

 Volume Serial Number is 328A-C899

 Directory of D:\Program

07/14/2013  12:09 PM    <DIR>          .
07/14/2013  12:09 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/16/2013  01:07 PM    <DIR>          IPS
07/14/2013  12:10 PM    <DIR>          IPS1
07/14/2013  12:12 PM    <DIR>          IPS2
07/14/2013  12:16 PM    <DIR>          IPS3
07/14/2013  01:50 PM    <DIR>          IPS4
07/14/2013  12:17 PM    <DIR>          IPS5
07/14/2013  12:17 PM    <DIR>          IPS6
07/14/2013  12:18 PM    <DIR>          IPS7
07/14/2013  12:18 PM    <DIR>          IPS8
06/16/2013  01:10 PM    <DIR>          IPSCommon
07/08/2013  12:32 PM    <DIR>          _IPS10
07/08/2013  12:32 PM    <DIR>          _IPS11
07/08/2013  12:32 PM    <DIR>          _IPS12
07/08/2013  12:32 PM    <DIR>          _IPS13
07/08/2013  12:32 PM    <DIR>          _IPS14
07/08/2013  12:57 PM    <DIR>          _IPS15
07/08/2013  12:32 PM    <DIR>          _IPS16
07/08/2013  03:38 PM    <DIR>          _IPS17
07/08/2013  12:32 PM    <DIR>          _IPS18
07/08/2013  12:32 PM    <DIR>          _IPS9
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              22 Dir(s)  770,968,162,304 bytes free
```

- requirements is to grep only IPS words that have a number like `IPS7` and not starting with `_`

I have used the following regex `IPS\d+\d*$` but this will grep words that starts with `_` also

How can I specify ! not `_`  ?

Comment: @Zaid Are we in an edit-war? I took out all the double-spacing, you put it back!

Comment: @Barmar : Looks like we encountered a race condition :). In any case it doesn't affect the question or answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\b` regexp operator to match a word boundary:

```
\bIPS\d+$
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to parse the output of the Windows `dir` command, which I assume is an attempt from you to list files in a directory. You should know that this is not a good way to accomplish that, and I will show you some alternatives. The answers to the regex are already given, so I won't bother with that.

Using a [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), `< ... >`, which is pretty much an emulation of how a shell expands wildcards.

```
my @ips = grep /^IPS\d+/,      # only IPS with number
          grep -d,             # only directories
          <D:/Program/IPS*>;   # list IPS file in the target dir
```

Using [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html).

```
opendir my $dh, "D:/Program" or die $!;
my @ips = grep /^IPS\d+/, readdir($dh);   
closedir $dh;
```

Using [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html). Do note that this option is recursive (will also list files in subdirectories):

```
use File::Find;    # core module in Perl 5
my @ips;
find(sub { push @ips, $File::Find::name if /^IPS\d+/ }, "D:/Program");
```

Each method has its own advantages. In your case, the most similar method to use would be the top one, the one using a glob.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negated character class:

```
[^_]IPS\d+$
```

Note that the second `\d` in your original regex is redundant because `\d+` will be greedy.

Answer (score 0):

add this before your `regex` it will look for word boundary and still not include in result before `IPS`

```
(?<=\b)
```

so your final regex looks like

```
(?<=\b)IPS\d+\d*$
```

Comment: The `\b` already is a zero-width assertion, so it doesn't have to be put into a lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

need to capture only Start with IP.

Please use the below regex.

(^IPS\d+)$